# editable oracle apex table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to create an editable table with long paragraphs in the left side and input columns in the right something like that:
[image: assessment table where values 5 and test are inputs]

kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a table might be one option:

```
SQL> create table assessment
  2    (id            number constraint pk_asmt primary key,
  3     elements      clob,
  4     bond_scale    number,
  5     remarks       varchar2(200)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

In Apex, create a "Report with Form on a table" layout; the Wizard will create Interactive report (so that you could review what you've got; don't display the whole `elements` column, maybe just a substring of first e.g. 200 characters) and a Form. Icon at the beginning of each report line will lead you to form so that you could update/delete those records. Also, report will have a `Create` button to let you create new entries.

Comment: thanx for ur reply, sadly they need all the characters is there any way like using JavaScript or another mehod?

Comment: Bullets and stuff? Apex 20.2 I work with offers two item types you could try: **Rich text Editor** and  **Markdown Editor**. If you're on version which doesn't support them, I'd say you're out of luck, unless you'll store a **file** into that column (BLOB, I suppose, because of formatting).

Comment: thanks again, the issue is not about bullets its about how to design a table that big and how can I design it in away that it will contain all of this information?

Comment: Oracle can handle that much data, you shouldn't worry about it. If it is a COLUMN datatype that bothers you, then: if VARCHAR2(4000) is enough, use it. If not, use CLOB (it accepts characters only; Character Large OBject). If you have various information that isn't text only, then use a BLOB (Binar Large OBject).